# Does the product of positive definite matrices have a positive trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{m}$ be a real symmetric semi-positive  definite matrices,  I want to know whether

$ tr (A_{1} \cdot A_{2} \cdots A_{m} ) \geq 0$ ?

When $m=2$, it seems a rather standard problem and has a "yes" answer.

Comment: Are the $A_k$ symmetric?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, all the $A_{k}$'s are symmetric.

Answer (score 7):

For $m\ge3$, no. Counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{6&-2\\ -2&1},
\ B = \pmatrix{1&-2\\ -2&8},
\ C = \pmatrix{10&8\\ 8&10},
\ ABC = \pmatrix{-124&-200\\ 56&88}.
$$
Note that $A,B,C$ are positive definite.

Comment: Yes, my assertion is not true. thanks !

Comment: Did you just try a bunch of numbers? That seems quite lucky.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I simply ran a numerical experiement.

Comment: @user1551 : I'd be interested in how you did that, I wouldn't have 'guessed' such an answer that easily, perhaps you should detail it in your answer!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva As kjetil b halvorsen mentioned in his answer, there simply isn't any good reason to believe that the equality holds. So, it's quite natural to search for a counterexample by computer, and I merely did that. The search program is nothing remarkable. You keep generating positive definite matrices until the equality is violated. There are simpler counterexamples where $A,B,C$ are positive semidefinite, but I decided to pick the current one, so that the OP will not edit the question and ask whether the equality is true when the matrices are positive definite.

Comment: @user1551 So you didn't even try to find a precise counterexample, you just waited till it popped out... okay, I can live with that :P

Answer (score 4):

Take $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. We have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} b & -a \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} 
 = 0 \ge 0.
$$
(Of course, $Ax$ is the rotation of $x$ by $\pi/2$, so $Ax \cdot x = 0$ always.) So $A$ is semi-positive definite. But
$$
A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
which has negative trace.

So I'm saying your assertion is false because I have a counter example.

EDIT : Just so that I don't look stupid, the symmetric assumption was not written in the question at the time this answer was written.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your counter example. But, a matrix is said to be semi-positive definite, it sould be symmetric firstly.

Comment: @mewmew Yes, but you added the symmetric part to your question later. There are non-symmetric positive semi-definite matrices.

Comment: IMHO saying "real positive (semi-)definite" implicitly implies "symmetric" (although it is better to say it explicitly) unless the contrary is explicitly stated and explained. According to [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) (which though not authoritative usually reflects the literature), "positive definite" for real matrices is defined only when they are symmetric, and for complex matrices the requirement $z^*Mz\in\mathbf R_{\geq0}$ alone (all complex vectors $z$) forces $M$ to be Hermitian (so symmetric if it is also real). Indeed $z=(i,i)^t$ would fail for $M=A$.

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen : I am a 'hater' of this symmetric assumption because not assuming it makes perfect sense, and the assumption that $A$ is symmetric is only relevant in the context of quadratic forms, where taking $A$ symmetric simply makes life easier ; the quadratic form can be represented by a symmetric matrix instead of a non-symmetric one in which the assymetric terms get killed anyway if we do the expansion of $x^{\top} A x$ to look at the form. If you are not in the context of quadratic forms (as I guess we are not right now, at least not explicitly), the symmetry assumption is weird..

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I think the point is that saying "positive (semi-)definite" implies interpreting $A$ as a quadratic form. Looking at general bilinear forms is perfectly valid of course, but the positive definite assumption just is not very useful in that setting. For me it is just a fact of experience that when people talk about definiteness, they are virtually always assuming symmetry. And in the complex (sesquilinear) setting, semi-definiteness even _implies_ symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

The general case should not be true for $m \ge 3$. Look at the proof for $m=2$:

$$  \DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace}
    \tr(AB) = \tr(A^{1/2} B A^{1/2} )
$$

which is clearly non-negative since the last matrix is symmetric positive definite.  But this proof does not work for $m \ge 3$ (try it! and you will see) so we should expect an counterexample in that case.  You should simple program a search for counterexamples in the three-matrix case, you will succeed.