# Show $\operatorname{tr}(X^T X Y^{T}\Lambda Y\Phi) \geq \lambda_n\operatorname{tr}(X^T X Y^{T} Y\Phi)$

Tags: inequality, trace

Let $X,Y\in R^{n\times p}$, $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n)$, $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n\gt 0$, $\Phi=\operatorname{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2,\cdots,\mu_p)$, $\mu_1\geq\mu_2\cdots\geq\mu_p\gt0$. Show the following inequality holds

$\operatorname{tr}(X^T X Y^{T}\Lambda Y\Phi) \geq \lambda_n\operatorname{tr}(X^T X Y^{T} Y\Phi)$

Can anybody help me out with this proof? Thank you in advance

Comment: At least for complex matrices, this inequality is not true. Do you have reason to believe it is true as stated?

Comment: These are real matrices.  I test some cases numerically and they all hold

Comment: This inequality would imply $\mathrm{tr}(ABC)\geq 0$ for positive semi-definite matrices $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $C$ diagonal. If $C$ is not diagonal, this is wrong, as show here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426708/does-the-product-of-positive-definite-matrices-have-a-positive-trace. I don't see how $C$ being diagonal would improve your situation (and there are counterexamples for complex values, so this would have to be something particular to real matrices).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be true for this special case, but hard to prove. Anyway, thanks for your comments.